# Angular Directive load function in .NET

Tags: angularjs, scope, directive

I 've got the function goToBoardbook() in doc1.cshtml which is working perfect..
In order to use it via Angular directive, my first step was to create some isolate scopes in the same .cshtml file:

```
    <div data-new-one
                 data-title="{{EventDetails.Name}}"
                 data-gotoboardbook="{{goToBoardBook()}}">
   </div>
```

Next step was to bind the scopes in the NewOneDirective.js file, in the following code:

```
var newOne = function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        templateUrl: "newone.html",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            title: '@',
            gotoboardbook: '@'
        },
        controller: ['$scope',
            function ($scope) {
                console.log($scope);
            }]}}
```

Finally I tried to read the data and use the function from another .cshtml file:

```
<button class="btn btn-main" ng-click="{{gotoboardbook}}" > dok1 </button >  
    <br>
    {{title}}
</div>
```

Even I can read the "title" element, I cannot use the function..
Has it to do on how I am "asking" for the function? Am I writing wrong the syntax?
Thank you

Comment: do use `&` instead of `@`, which indicates you can pass `expression` to directive

Comment: You are right about the syntax(my mistake), but unfortunatelly still not working

Comment: Do look at below answer.. I felt that instead of adding big comment, why shouldn't I add an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Do use `&` for expression binding, `@` is used for one way binding.

```
scope: {
   title: '@',
   gotoboardbook: '&' //changed to `&`
},
```

**Markup**

```
<div data-new-one
    data-title="{{EventDetails.Name}}"
    data-gotoboardbook="goToBoardBook()">
```

**Directive template**

```
<button class="btn btn-main" ng-click="gotoboardbook()" > dok1 </button >  
    <br>
    {{title}}
</div>
```